gradients created in SVGjs don't render
I am working out bugs in an SVG editing program. So far most images import correctly, but I'm having problems with gradients.
A working version of the code is at geewhiz.ai
The following image does not load correctly:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" id="svg_drawing" 
sodipodi:version="0.32" inkscape:version="1.2 (dc2aedaf03, 2022-05-15)" 
sodipodi:docname="lineargradient3.svg" 
inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 
  xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0, 0, 800, 1000">
  <defs id="defs4">
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient3193" x1="100.57143" x2="328.57143">
      <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#0000ff" offset="0"></stop>
      <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#00ff00" offset="0.5"></stop>
      <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#ff0000" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" xlink:href="#linearGradient3193"
    id="linearGradient3199" x1="128.57143" y1="289.50504" x2="425.71428" y2="289.50504" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" xlink:href="#linearGradient3193" id="linearGradient3299" x1="425.71428" y1="250.50504" x2="425.71428" y2="408.04504" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient2848">
      <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#5b6879" offset="0"></stop>
      <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#fc7c90" offset="0.9"></stop>
      <stop stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#00ff00" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" xlink:href="#linearGradient2848" id="linearGradient2854" x1="605.78571" y1="693.82843" x2="679.82141" y2="416.68555" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"></linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="397.14285" height="157.14285" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="10"
    fill="url(#linearGradient3199)" 
    fill-opacity="1" id="rect3191" x="128.57143" y="160.93361"></rect>
  <rect width="297.14285" height="157.14285" style="fill:url(#linearGradient3299);fill-opacity:1" id="rect3192" x="528.57143" y="250.93361"></rect>
  <rect width="297.14285" height="257.14285" style="fill:url(#linearGradient2854);fill-opacity:1" id="rect3193" x="128.57143" y="460.93361"></rect>
  <rect width="297.14285" height="257.14285" style="fill:url(#linearGradient2854);fill-opacity:1" id="rect3194" x="428.57143" y="460.93361"></rect>
  <rect width="100" height="100" id="svg33" x="20.57143" y="20.93361" fill="#0338833"></rect>
</svg>

Note that this image is what I captured from the browser using dev tools as rendered by my code, and if it is placed inline in the normal manner, it renders just fine. It is just not rendering the linear gradients in the editor window like I need it to.
The page itself runs using Vue3, and I suppose this could be why I have this problem, perhaps Vue3 is protecting the DOM somehow to not permit this. I am using SVGjs to render the image into a $ref(erenced) div on the page. The various url(#linearGradientXXXX) are not found.
To duplicate this bug, copy the svg image (or any other one having linear gradients) to your computer, go to http://geewhiz.ai and use the button on the top right to load the svg image. It will show up, there's some things that render in the image, but not any of the linear gradients. If you go to the Popup Demo tab, the exact same image works when it is loaded inline.

Can you reproduce the error locally on a dev server?

The code at http://geewhiz.ai is not minimized and has source maps.
I've added the SVG to the Popup Control Demo tab, to show that in normal inline rendering it works.

I asked ChatGPT this question several ways. It validated that the svg is correct, should render, and expressly suggested that I post it here. It has a working code example at geewhiz.ai, it isn't unclear at all

I was using an svg parser to construct the svg using the methods in svgJs.
It is entirely unnecessary, this works:
handleFileContent(content: string) {
   const drawing: Svg = SVG(vueContentRef);
   drawing.svg(content);
}

Part of the reason for doing it the original way was I found the parser first. I should have realized that a tool like this could parse svg, like duh.
Now I have to write a handler that steps thru the rendered elements and adds the events to them that I need, but it is actually a relief that I don't have to handle building up the svg.
